# My desktop turned black, I see the status bar at the top, but cannot see the wallpaper or dock

Tags: macbook-pro

This happened two days ago on my MacBook Air 2011.  When I log into other accounts on the Mac, the wallpaper and dock are there.  So this only happens on the one account.  I am sure this is a simple fix, but want this account back as all my photos and files are on it.  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered.

Comment: Try rebooting it.

Comment: Tried that, it comes back with same issue.